# Templating dust: after inserting a template is not loaded images from css

Tags: css, mootools, background-image, less, template-engine

The project structure is as follows:
backbone - MVC
Dust - template
Mootools - operation with the DOM
LESS - generate CSS

Load through the JSON and compile with dust template. Then, using mootools insert into the page:

```
new Request.JSON({url: 'templates/basis.json',
   onFailure: function(){
  console.log('error');
},
onSuccess: function(responseJSON){

   dust.loadSource(dust.compile(responseJSON.basis, "intro"));

   dust.render("intro", {name: "Fred"}, function(err, out) {
         $('init').set('html', out);
         return out;
   });
}).get();
```

By the time of inserting a ready template to a page in the browser has already compiled hanging styles. And that's the main catch: **all of the styles are applied, except for purposes of background images**.

I tried to specify styles directly without less, tried to load an image in base64. And yet revealed how you can show the same image with the inspection element with a background image to reassign the new path. Then yes, there is.

In what may be the problem?

**UPD: Hmm. The solution is found. Background images should not be given background-repeat of one of the axes, or absent. That is, this attribute must be specified or not, or just be a repeat. Very strange behavior.**

Comment: You should add your update as an answer when you can. And welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 1):

In general, the problem was in my inattention. It is unfortunate that I have killed so many at this time, because initially I was searching for, not where needed.
In fact, the problem was in the css: accidentally transported from another attribute block (background-position: 0 80px;), which is why the picture was not visible. Everything up to the limit was stupidly. =)

But everything else is working with a bang, as expected. =)